# What's the best practice to draw lines between angular components based on component values?

Tags: html, angular, components, line

I want to connect different angular(7) components of type A and B with lines and text. The lines can be horizontal or diagonal. A relation between a component of type A and B is held by a component C that stores the ID of an A, the ID of a B and text that needs to be displayed above the line. At least A and B should be responsive components and not a static image. 
I create As and Bs with ngFor in a parent display component. Then I'd have to iterate over Cs to draw the lines. This implies multiple problems:
1. What's the best practice to draw such lines with text between components?
2. How can I get the positions of the components A and B? I read that querying the DOM is bad practice in angular.

From what I have found:
Canvas: As far as I understood it, the problem with canvas is, that it's - once created - a static image. But I need to query my As and Bs position to draw Cs.
SVG: I can create a line with text using svg, but I'm not sure if that's a good approach, because the main problem is connection my custom components A and B: One way could be to draw As and Bs within SVG, while another one would be an SVG image between the "columns" for As and Bs displaying only the lines. In any way I have to admit that I'm overwhelmed, so I want to make sure to move into the right direction of design.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  templateUrl: './a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a.component.css']
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() a: A;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  templateUrl: './b.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./b.component.css']
})
export class BComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() b: B;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```
export class A{
    id: string;
}
```

```
export class B{
    id: string;
}
```

```
export class C{
    aID: string;
    bID: string;
    value: string;
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-display',
  templateUrl: './display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display.component.css']
})
export class DisplayComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() as: A [] = [];
        @Input() bs: B [] = [];
        @Input() cs: C [] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

display html:

```
<div class="frame">

<div class="as" [style.grid-area]="'as'">
     <app-a id="{{ a.id }}" *ngFor="let a of as" [a]="a"></app-a>
</div>
<div class="bs" [style.grid-area]="'bs'">
     <app-b id="{{ b.id }}" *ngFor="let b of bs" [b]="b"></app-b>
</div>

<!-- Draw line now for every c of cs between corresponding a and b -->

</div>
```

display css:

```
.frame {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "as cs bs";
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-row-gap: 16px;
    grid-column-gap: 16px;
}
```

Actual:

```
A1        B1



A2        B2
```

Expected:

```
A1 --10-- B1
        /
     20
   /  
A2        B2
```

Comment: There's so many third-party libraries that solve this problem. I would recommend looking at one of them if you're having difficulty trying to understand how you could do it yourself. It's kind of a tricky problem to solve for a beginner. A quick Google search found me this: http://js.cytoscape.org/

Comment: I finally came up to a solution with this framework: https://anseki.github.io/leader-line/ . It's very well documented, illustrated and usable.